# Trouble connecting to mysql using php5 LAMP server

Tags: server, lubuntu, apache2, php, lamp

I am trying to set up a LAMP server on lubuntu 14.04.5, I erased index.html and replaced it with :

`/var/www/html/index.php` 
 
 Problem is that everything before this `<?php` tag executes and this seems to crash it. I do not know why, is it because I MUST have index.html?

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost:3306";
$dbuser = "user1";
$dbpass = "pass1";
$connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(!$connection){
die("connection error " . mysqli_error());
}
echo "connected successfully";
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

So in my php error log I get undefined function mysqli_connect(). How do I make this an available function?

When I do aptitude search php5-mysql an i shows up meaning that it is installed. And there are no other mysql modules except for mysqlnd which I don't think I need since its just native directory and mysqlnd-ms How do I resolve this?

edit: I think I need to add the mysqli extension but having trouble locating it.

Comment: Is this right `mysqli_erro()`, should it not be `mysqli_error()`?

Comment: Please post the entire file content and also print-screen of the result.

Comment: Sorry I fixed that mysqli_error(), just a typo

Comment: @pa4080 entire file is just html stuff like head title body etc. And print-screen is just nothing nill, nada. In view page source all I see is all the code pre the <?php tag. also I have updated the question

Comment: @DavidFoerster not completely a  programming issue since I didn't have php5-mysql installed, but I understand if you think it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SO what I did was `sudo apt-get install php5-mysql` Then I was still getting the same webpage so I thought nothing happened, but after checking the `/var/log/php5/error.log` It turns out the error changed from "undefined command mysqli_connect()" to some code related error like "mysqli_error requires 1 parameter and "object of class mysqli could not be converted to string" and "unknown mysql server 'localhost:3306'". localhost:3306 got changed to just locahost. so after updating my code, everything works fine.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Connecting MySQL Server</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <?php
         $dbhost = 'localhost';
         $dbuser = 'user1';
         $dbpass = 'pass1';
         $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
         if(! $conn ) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_connect_error());
         }
         echo 'Connected successfully';
         mysqli_close($conn);
      ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code has syntax errors right code to use:

```
<?php
    $dbhost = "localhost:3306";
    $dbuser = "user1";
    $dbpass = "pass1";
    $connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    if(!$connection){
        die("connection error " . mysqli_error());
    }
    echo "connected successfully";
    mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Errors:

- `mysqli_erro()` ==> `mysqli_error()`
- `dbpass`  ==> `$dbpass`

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, I hand wrote the code so those errors are only present here.

Comment: This `<?php tag executes and this seems to crash it` isn't clear

Comment: Sorry I mean to say, that my html <title> </title> appears and looking at view page source everything before the <?php tag appears. So I think the php is crashing some how.

Comment: Check the error log. This defaults to /var/log/apache2/error.log
If php crashes, it will usually note this in the log. Also, for local development, printing warnings and errors may make a lot of sense.

Comment: Thank you, so it turns out that it does not know what mysqli_connect is

Comment: Thank you, so it turns out that it does not know what mysqli_connect is. I did sudo apt-get install php5-mysql but this didn't fix the problem either

Answer (score 0):

You say you did this...

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

And you never mention doing this, which is also required...

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Just because you install php5-mysql, doesn't mean Apache has loaded either PHP or the PHP MySQL module.

You can find out for sure what's occurring by creating a phpinfo.php file containing...

```
<?php
print_r (phpinfo());
?>
```

Then check + ensure both PHP is loaded + PHP mysql module is loaded.

When in doubt, always check your phpinfo.php file output as your first debugging step.

Many times having this simple output, quickly resolves complex problems.